# Convert space seperated values of a column to single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with values as mentioned below.

```
Transaction_ID
GT980 FR563
BR923 DE498 QS347
HB743
```

How can I convert and bring the results like below. I need to split the value with space delimiter. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved.

```
 Transaction_ID
   GT980 
   FR563
   BR923 
   DE498 
   QS347
   HB743
```

Comment: Sql-server `<>` MySQL. Which one are you using? Also, splitting strings is a very common task.  What issues are you having with the solutions found in the archives?

Comment: And what is the SQL server version?

Comment: @SOS - I am using SQL server

Comment: @Coder1991 - SSMS V.17.9

Comment: @Learner - SSMS is an IDE. We mean what version of SQL Server. `SELECT @@version`.  SQL Server 2017+ supports [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Lots of examples in the archives too https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+string_split

Comment: @SOS - SQL server 2016

Comment: Did you search the archives? This question comes up ... a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string split function in SQLl.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSplitString
( 
  @string VARCHAR(MAX), 
  @delimiter VARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata VARCHAR(MAX)) 
BEGIN 

  DECLARE @Xml XML

  SET @Xml = CAST(('<a>'+REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,'</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

  INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)
    SELECT ltrim(rtrim(A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')))  FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(a)

  RETURN 
END
```

and then use it as

```
select cs.* 
from yourtable
cross apply fnSplitString (Transaction_ID, ' ') cs
```

Comment: Multi-line table value functions are well known to perform poorly. An inline table value function would be far better, or just use the inbuilt function, `STRING_SPLIT`. Either would be much faster.